# No security updates for .NET 3.5 in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, .net-framework

In Windows 10 Pro (November 2014 build) I enabled .NET 3.5 via Windows Features:

[image]

Windows downloaded and installed the required components.

I then initiated a Windows Update but, unexpectedly, no updates were found for .NET 3.5. Weird, because in Windows 8.x you get a whole bunch of .NET 3.5 security updates.

Can anyone confirm which of the following is true:

1. In Windows 10, when you enable .NET 3.5, the components downloaded are *already* up-to-date and do not require further security updates.
2. Windows 10 has royally screwed something up again and is not picking up on security updates that it *should* be.

Comment: You know if Microsoft just documented these things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest security update I can find is from [2014](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44081) - before the mainstream release of Windows 10. As such, I'd expect all these are bundled in, and should another release you'll receive it via Windows update.